# Image is not shown in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, windows, qt

## Description

I wrote following Qt code. And Make executable file for Windows (*.exe). But Image (JPG) is not shown in QGraphicsScene. And I had already checked whether the path to image is correct. In following code, MyQGraphicsScene is derived class inherits QGraphicsScene class.

I compiled same code in macOS. Then, Executable file (ELF) for macOS ran correctly. Image file was shown in its component. I feel starange that source code is same. But the result is different by environment.

## Development environment

- Windows 10
- Qt version : 5.7.0
- C++ Compiler : Microsoft Visual C++ Ver.14.0 (MSVC2015)

## Source code

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QIcon>
#include "TrainingData.h"
#include "trainingDataMaker.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QGraphicsItem *curGItem;
    QListWidgetItem *listItem;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new MyQGraphicsScene(QRectF(0, 0, 400, 400));
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    listItem = new QListWidgetItem();
    listItem->setIcon(QIcon("data/000001.jpg"));
    ui->imgListWidget->addItem(listItem);
    listItem = new QListWidgetItem();
    listItem->setIcon(QIcon("data/000276.jpg"));
    ui->imgListWidget->addItem(listItem);
    ui->imgListWidget->setIconSize(QSize(300,100));


    QPixmap pixmap;
    QImage img("data/000001.jpg");
    QTransform transForm;
    pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *imgPixmap = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap);
    transForm = QTransform();
    transForm.scale(0.1, 0.1);
    imgPixmap->setTransform(transForm);
    scene->addItem(imgPixmap);

    //connect(scene, SIGNAL(changed(const QList<QRectF> &)), imgPixmap, SLOT(chgSize(const QList<QRectF> &)));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As result, Cause of this issue is my **misunderstanding of current directory** in case that the application is launched from IDE. Current directory is (a) in following diagram.

## Directory structure before

```
[Output directory is specified in build configuration] - (a)
  |- debug - (b)
  |    |- test.exe // executable file of this application
  |    |- data
  |        |-000001.jpg
  |- release
```

Therefore, I should have located "data" directory includes image files in directory (a) as following diagram. I'm feeling strange this specification of IDE. Of course, Current directory is same diretory of exe file in case that application launch directly(Doublu-clicking exe file)  .

## Directory structure after

```
[Output directory is specified in build configuration] - (a)
  |- debug - (b)
  |    |- test.exe // executable file of this application
  |- release
  |- data
      |-000001.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

> I compiled same code in macOS. Then, Executable file (ELF) for macOS
>   ran correctly. Image file was shown in its component. I feel starange
>   that source code is same. But the result is different by environment.

Since it works under MacOS/X but not under Windows, one likely explanation is that it's a distribution/environmental problem.  In particular, perhaps your program can't find Qt's imageformat plugin (e.g. qjpeg4.dll or qjpeg5.dll) under Windows, and that is why the image is not being displayed.

To test that theory, you could copy the qjpeg*.dll plugin file into the same folder as your .exe file, and then re-run your program and see if that makes it behave better.  Alternatively, if you don't want to mess with image format plugins, you could convert your .jpg file to another file format that Qt includes native (i.e. non-plugin-based) support for, such as BMP or PNG, and use that instead.

Comment: Thank you for valuable advice. I could not find qjpeg[4|5[.dll under Qt install directory. But I found qjpeg.dll.

Comment: So I copy this qjpeg.dll to same directory with exe file. And ran application. But image file still was not shown.

Comment: Also I convert image file format JPG to PNG. But image file was not shown.

Comment: As the result, Path to image file was wrong. For detail, I'll report in following. I'm sorry.